# React Native supposed componentwillmount is not working in React hooks version

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello i am building a log in screen in react native and I want to make a remember info but the info stills there If I change the screen when It supposed to be cleared If the checkbox is false, i am using secure store to access the storage

I searched on internet and the way to solve it is to make a componentwillmount after everything is rendered but the suppose component in useeffect is not working

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Card, Icon, Input, CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';

const Login = (props) => {

    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [remember, setRemember] = useState(false);
    

useEffect(() => {
    SecureStore.getItemAsync('userinfo')
        .then((userdata) => {
            let userinfo = JSON.parse(userdata);
            if (userinfo) {
                setUsername(userinfo.username);
                setPassword(userinfo.password);
                setRemember(true);
            }
        })
}, [])

const handleLogin = () => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(username, password, remember));
    if (remember === true) {
        SecureStore.setItemAsync(
                'userinfo',
                JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password })
            )
            .catch(error => console.log(`Could not save user info ${error}`));
    }
    else {
        SecureStore.deleteItemAsync('userinfo')
            .catch(error => console.log(`Could not save user info ${error}`));
    }
}

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Input 
                placeholder='Username'
                leftIcon={{ type: 'font-awesome', name: 'user-o' }}
                onChangeText={(username) => setUsername(username)}
                inputContainerStyle={styles.formInput}
                />
            <Input 
                placeholder='Password'
                leftIcon={{ type: 'font-awesome', name: 'key' }}
                onChangeText={(password) => setPassword(password)}
                inputContainerStyle={styles.formInput}
                />
            <CheckBox
                title='Remember Me'
                center
                checked={remember}
                onPress={() => setRemember(!remember)}
                containerStyle={styles.formCheckbox}
                />
            <View style={styles.formButton}>
                <Button
                    onPress={() => handleLogin()}
                    title='Login'
                    color='#512DA8'
                    />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: It is illegal to use async for useEffect callback.

Comment: don't use async-await in use effect.

Comment: Not only you don't need any of those `async-awaits`, but you also shouldn't use `return` there either.

Comment: @VigneshVPai I have already fixed all of these issues but it still not working